# Heroku remove linked github account

Tags: github, heroku

I am new to Heroku so just getting the hang of things!

Anyway... I added the wrong account on the "Settings" page of my Heroku application. This would mean that I could add the repo that's connected to my normal account to access the CI pipeline stuff. But since it's the wrong account I cannot add my repo to the CI. But I also cannot remove the account?

Has anyone been able to remove an account they didn't mean to add?

[image]

I would like to remove this account and re-add my new one with the correct repo on it.